# Passing variable from Activity to Adapter

Tags: java, android

I want to pass a variable from an activity to an adapter.
Don't know where I did the mistake.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private int weight;
    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
.....
}
```

But I can't acces this method in my Activity

```
public class mActivity extends Activity {
    CustomListAdapter expandableListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.emergency_activity);

        expandableListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this);
        //expandableListAdapter.setWeight(5);
...
```

"expandableListAdapter can not resolved to a type"

Comment: Did you mean to have `expandableListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this);`? You are declaring it as one type then trying to instantiate it as another.

Comment: you should post it as an answer bro @codeMagic

Comment: Can you please post the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the variable as one type

```
CustomListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
```

then try to instantiate it as another

```
expandableListAdapter = new EmergencyListAdapter(this);
```

this could produce a couple different errors but here, your IDE thinks it is a new variable without a declared type.

You either need to change the declared type to `EmergencyListAdapter` or instantiate it as `new CustomListAdapter()` (assuming that class has an empty constructor).

Comment: Sorry, this was a mistake by me during coping the text. The problem still exists. Editet my question.

Comment: And you are still getting this error, "expandableListAdapter can not resolved to a type"? Do you have any other errors?

Comment: There was a spellingmistake. Searched for it since houres. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your exapndableListAdapter is not being created. You are creating EmergencyListAdapter (which you haven't provided code for).

What you want to do is probbbaly this:

```
expandableListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this);
```

then you should be able to do:

```
expandableListAdapter.setWeight(5);
```

Good luck.